# STUFF Function producing multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Though its a very simple query but still i don't know where am i going wrong in the below query

```
SELECT 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Package.Name  FROM Package WHERE Subscribed.PackID = Package.ID 
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'') [PackName]
FROM Subscribed  
WHERE 
Subscribed.UsrID = 1234 AND 
Subscribed.DateOfEnd <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND
(Subscribed.Status = 0 OR Subscribed.Status = 1)
```

Because i am expecting the the result as shown below :

```
PackName
---------------------------------
Demo Notification, EditedPackage
```

But this is the result i am getting as shown below

```
PackName
---------------------------------
Demo Notification
EditedPackage
```

So any comments where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row, then move all the logic into the subquery:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + p.Name 
              FROM Package p JOIN
                   Subscribed s
                   ON s.PackID = p.ID 
              WHERE s.UsrID = 1234 AND 
                    s.DateOfEnd <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND
                    s.Status IN (0, 1)
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''
            ) as [PackName];
```

Otherwise, you'll get a separate row for each row in the `Subscribed` table.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Try in following:

```
SELECT 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Package.Name AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]  
       FROM Package 
       WHERE Subscribed.PackID = Package.ID 
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
       .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' ') [PackName]
FROM Subscribed  
WHERE 
Subscribed.UsrID = 1234 AND 
Subscribed.DateOfEnd <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND
(Subscribed.Status = 0 OR Subscribed.Status = 1)
```

Comment: getting one row but only the last row i ain't getting the result as i expected from the above query, because your query will return me only the last row. i.e. `EditedPackage` but i want `Demo Notification, EditedPackage`

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you need to GROUP or use DISTINCT as shown here

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      Subscribed.UsrID
    , ca.PackName
FROM Subscribed
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  STUFF((
                        SELECT
                              ', ' + Package.Name
                        FROM Package
                        WHERE Subscribed.PackID = Package.ID
                        FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
                  )
                  .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ' ') [PackName]
      ) ca
WHERE Subscribed.UsrID = 1234
      AND Subscribed.DateOfEnd <= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
      AND (Subscribed.Status = 0
      OR Subscribed.Status = 1)
```

I have also used CROSS APPLY so that the subquery forms part of the FROM clause